# Designing iterators for a new programming language

Tags: lambda, programming-languages, closures, return

I am considering various ways of having an each() method wrap around iterating in a programming language. I came up with the following idea of "inline functions with yields". Its purpose is to avoid closures with nonlocal returns which I've also seen called block lambdas. Example pseudocode with explanation after it:

```
class LinkedList
    iterator()
        # construct and return iterator

    inline each()
        iter = iterator()
        while iter.hasNext()
            yield iter.next()

main()
    list = LinkedList.new
    # add stuff to linked list

    list.each()
        # somehow the yield in each() populates v
        print v
        if v == "foo"
            return
```

The `inline` keyword means the `each()` invocation is inlined when it is called, `yield` is replaced with the indented code block at the invocation site, and the "yielded" expression, `iter.next()` in the example, is passed to that indented code block as a variable as well. In effect the code for `main()` is transformed to the following

```
main()
    list = LinkedList.new
    # add stuff to linked list

    # list.each() call transformed
    iter = list.iterator()
    while iter.hasNext()
        v = iter.next()
        print v
        if v == "foo"
            return
```

The indented code block after `list.each()` isn't being passed as a closure to `each()` to be executed. If it were then the meaning of the return statement would be confusing. Would it mean return from the closure, return from `each()`, or return from `main()`.

The return statement in `main()` returns from `main()` because `each()` is being inlined into the code of `main()`. This avoids the complications of closures with nonlocal returns.

The issue I am having is how to populate the variable `v` in the example pseudocode given at the top. I can't think of a good syntax that is reasonable. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just do it sort of like any other language's `for each` loop.  Java's goes like `for(fooType foo: fooList) proc;`.  IIRC, Python goes like `for foo in fooList: proc`.  PostScript goes `fooList proc forall`.  Each of those constructs iterates through `fooList`, executing `proc` for each `foo` in `fooList`.  Except for the PostScript one, they all fetch  `fooList.iterator()` or `fooList.__iter__()` and then use `it.next()` to run through all the its elements, checking if it is done by either using `it.hasNext()` or listening for a `StopIteration` exception.  If you want programmers to define the behavior in that construct by defining an `fooList.each()` method rather than `fooList.iterator()` (or whatever), go ahead.  I am just not sure why you would want to name your iterator generation method `each`.  But if thats really what you want, go ahead.

Answer (score 1):

`list.each(v)` would seem to be the logical solution